# Cannot find name onUnsubscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

Got this error `Cannot find name onUnsubscribe`

What should I import ?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <b>Angular 2 Component Using Observables!</b>

      <h5 style="margin-bottom: 0">VALUES</h5>
      <pre><code>{{value}}</code></pre>

      <h5 style="margin-bottom: 0">SUBSCRIBED</h5>
      <pre><code>{{subscribed}}</code></pre>

      <h5 style="margin-bottom: 0">STATUS</h5>
      <pre><code>{{status}}</code></pre>

      <button style="margin-top: 2rem" (click)="init()">Init</button>
  `
})
export class MyApp {

  private data: Observable<string>;
  private value: string;
  private subscribed: boolean;
  private status: string;

    init() {

        this.data = new Observable(observer => {
            let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                observer.next('You will never see this message');
            }, 2000);

            this.status = 'Started';

            return onUnsubscribe = () => {
                this.subscribed = false;
                this.status = 'Finished';
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            }
        });

        let subscription = this.data.subscribe(
            value => this.value = value,
            error => console.log(error),
            () => this.status = 'Finished';
        );
        this.subscribed = true;

        setTimeout(() => {
          subscription.unsubscribe();
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0MfW5d?p=preview

It seems ng2 is quite different back then. I think data should be `Observable<string>`. I have no idea why `plnkr` code works.

This onUnsubscribe is some sort a custom callback.

Comment: Can you explain what your trying

Comment: Just a WAG, but should onUnsubscribe = () =>  not be onUnsubscribe() => ? Are you returning the function onUnsubscribe, or chaining a declaration - a = b => c? I think you've got an extra = in there.

Comment: updated. I tried the code in ng4 project but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plunker works because there is no typechecking.

You don't have to (shouldn't) name the return function. Observables will call their return function when they are completed.

```
return () => {
    this.subscribed = false;
    this.status = 'Finished';
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}
```

Updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/u7vbcY?p=preview